# Application in xamarin.mac that takes screenshots and system idle time

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

Actually, I'm new to 'xamarin.mac' applications and I'm trying an application that takes screenshot frequently also captures system idle time on login.So far I've managed to capture screenshot but How to take system idle time?

I've gone through 'NSEvents'.But I cannot figure it out how to implement those
event against button click.

I just want the system idle time count that starts on login.

Comment: `IOKit` is listed as an unsupported framework for Xamarin.Mac and thus there is no prebuilt binding for it. You are looking for the IOServiceGetMatchingServices function (passing IOHIDSystem) and it returns a dict (you have to find the HIDIdleTime key (i think, it has been awhile). These are C-based kernel calls so they can be PInvoke by C# (some pointers are needed, but nothing to crazy). I think these were defined in the `foundation.h` header, but it might be iokitlib.h now.

Comment: But is there any way to put these in c# code, not in objective c?

Comment: I figured it out. Actually it was not any application event which I was looking for earlier rather it is an OS event and I'm able to take the output using shell script.Now it is working as expected. Thanks for your help